# Error in express even after installing nodemon and express through npm

Tags: node.js, express, npm, routes, nodemon

i have provided package.json and then express as dependency and then install both nodemon and express through npm but when i run it through nodemon as

```
PS E:\Web Work\nodejs> nodemon routing.js
```

THE Error its Show is that

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node routing.js`
events.js:160
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
 ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
```

Comment: You will need to show code, not just the stack trace.

Comment: the code is ok and can execute through node express command